# With RequireJS, Backbone requires jquery but can't find it?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, requirejs

I'm using RequireJS and Backbone.js in my project, and the latest version of Backbone, when detecting if using RequireJS, automatically add "jquery" to the list of required modules.

I'm using jQuery, but it's already defined in the DOM and it's not loaded in RequireJS as "jquery" but as "jQuery" from the global space (loaded via the DOM).

This results in an error :

```
Uncaught Error: Script error for: jQuery
```

How can I do to indicate to Backbone to stop trying to load "jquery"?

Comment: "I'm using jQuery, but it's already defined in the DOM and it's not loaded in RequireJS as "jquery" but as "jQuery"." This to me means that you're using two jQueries, one loaded outside RequireJS ("already defined in the DOM") **and** one which *not* loaded by RequireJS as "jquery" but [*is* loaded by RequireJS] as "jQuery". If this is not the case, you might want to rephrase it.

Comment: I rephrased it, it's better ?

Comment: It is definitely better. Now though I would want to see how you load the global space jQuery in RequireJS because that may very well be where the issue arises. Seeing how you configure RequireJS would also help because a lot of issues originate there.

Comment: No, the problem is here : http://backbonejs.org/backbone.js, line 12 : `define(['underscore', 'jquery', 'exports'], `. WHY "jquery" ?!

Comment: Nope, this is not the problem.